# How to configure Oracle Data Access Components on Windows Server

Tags: oracle, iis-7.5

I have a .Net application which connects to an Oracle database via ODAC. I developed this locally using ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio on my client. Its works fine.

I have now tried deploying this to a Windows 2008 Server. I installed ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) XCopy to c:\oracle and have my path set so "C:\oracle;C:\oracle\bin;"

However at the point the application tries to connect to Oracle I get

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.GetDbProviderFactorySecure() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I am at a loss to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: It's not enough to just copy the files and set the path, you need to change some configuration on the server too.  An easy way to accomplish that would be to use the Oracle Setup instead of xcopy.

Comment: I ran the install.bat file which is part of the ODAC XCopy package. I thought that was supposed to configure everything for me?

Comment: Is your server 32 bits or 64 bits?  If 64 bits, which version of the Oracle components did you install?

Comment: Server is 64bit. I think I tried the 64bit package but with no success. I'll try again now I have got it working under 32 bit. See answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true under the Application Pool in IIS made it work. This is despite having the application compile to x86 rather than Any CPU.